# Does await return the execution back to main thread immediately?

Tags: c#, async-await

I have this code in test application and it turns out from the output that the execution does not return to main thread on encountering the await keyword.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Download();
            Console.WriteLine("Back to Main");
        }

        async static Task Download()
        {
            await Test();
            Console.WriteLine("Back to Download");
        }

        async static Task Test()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            Console.WriteLine("Test Completed");
        }
    }
}
```

I was expecting console to show the output as below :

Back to Main

Test Completed

Back to Download

but it shows:

Test Completed

Back to Download

Back to Main

Comment: Note that you `await` a `Task`: you do not await a method call. So `await Test()` executes `Test()` until it returns a `Task`, and then awaits that `Task` which `Test` returned. Your code does is actually synchronous  (`Test` doesn't actually await anything, and you should get a warning from this), so when `Test` returns, it returns a `Task` which has already completed. the `await` in `Download` therefore completes synchronously as well. If you want to make your code asynchronous, change that `Thread.Sleep` into `await Task.Delay`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compile your code, you get a CS1998, which says

> This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.

So, `Test()` runs synchronously. If you want to have it asynchronous, use

```
async static Task Test()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("Test Completed");
}
```

If you want additional code in `Download()` to run while your download is still in progress, also use

```
async static Task Download()
{
    var test = Test();
    Console.WriteLine("Back to Download");
    await test;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Await continues execution after the awaited task has completed. That task may complete synchronously or asynchronously. There is not really any way to tell just by looking at a method signature what it will be.

In this particular case the `Test()` is completely synchronous. There is no asynchronous code going on at all in the example, so the same as if you removed all the async/task/await.

Change the Download method to this to produce the result you expect:

```
async static Task Download()
    {
        await Task.Run(() => Test());
        Console.WriteLine("Back to Download");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This updated code works to give the output:

Back to Main

Test Completed

Back to Download

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task t1 = Download();
            Console.WriteLine("Back to Main");
            await t1;
        }

        async static Task Download()
        {
            await Task.Run(() => Test());
            Console.WriteLine("Back to Download");
        }

        static void Test()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Console.WriteLine("Test Completed");
        }
    }
}
```